# Apache POI parse currency to BigDecimal with Event Model (XSSFReader)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using the event model (not workbook) and I'm trying to get currency cells returned to me without any currency symbols in the string in my SheetHandler. I believe the solution lives in my own overridden version of the DataFormatter's formatRawCellContents, which I've already begun to handle years with dates.

When I parse $1,000.00 for example, I'm getting a formatIndex of 165 and a format string of `" ""$"* #,##0" ";" ""$"* \(#,##0\);" ""$"* "- "`

I don't understand enough about the patterns here to know what to look for, nor what to set the new formatString to be to have it return it as is. I believe there should be some sort of formatCache but I don't know how to access that directly.

I believe I could do a find and replace on currency symbols (while I expect $, I have no idea what might be given), or use the NumberFormat option. But I think those aren't as clean and I'd like to learn a better approach.

Comment: Detect it's a currency from the format index, then format the string of the value into a number of the right format as you want?

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is I don't know what object to use to determine the format index is a currency. I haven't seen any documentation out there showing how to go from index to type or any util methods to do so.

Comment: All the built in ones are in https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html but people can (and do...) define their own currency ones that are similar but subtly different...

Comment: So I finally understood that what you meant was that Excel users set up their own custom formats because I found the format in the Custom Format options in Excel. What I've done for the currency one is removed the $ and , in the string formattedValue while processing the cell. But now I've come across other ones. What do you suggest I do? Anytime I see a formatIndex > 163, set it to 0? I don't really need their format. Most recently I found an invalid cell/format that throws an exception.

Comment: Depends how sure you want to be, but checking the format string for a few likely currency symbols may be your best bet